# NP-complete to determine vertex cover

Tags: algorithm

Is it right that "it is NP-complete to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"???

and

is it right that " it takes linear time to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"???

One more, is it right to say that " No NP-complete problem can be solved in polynomial time unless the VERTEX COVER problem admits a polynomial-time algorithm."???

Comment: In *general* case vertex cover is *NP-complete*. For *some kind* of graphs it can well be linear or even constant time (e.g. for graghs that have 99 or less vertixes) complexity

Comment: One more, is it right to say that " No NP-complete problem can be solved in polynomial time unless the VERTEX COVER problem admits a polynomial-time algorithm."???

Comment: @wewtie as this is the definition of NP-complete: yes

Comment: We don't know if any NP-Complete problem can (*general case*) be solved in polynomial time. It's a so called Millenium Problem. If Vertex Cover can be solved (as well as any other NP-complete problem) than all the other NP-complete problems can be solved.

Comment: 'is it right that " it takes linear time to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"???' No.

Answer (score 1):

"is it NP-complete to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"

### Pedantically: no.

This problem can be solved in polynomial time.  However, the following algorithm is completely useless in practice.

The approach for a graph with n vertices is simply to test all C(n,99) possible choices of vertex cover.  For each choice, we test all edges (at most n*(n-1) edges in the graph) to see if either of their vertices are included.

There are fewer than `n^99` ways of choosing the vertex cover, so overall this algorithm has polynomial complexity of `n^101`.

As noted by j_random_hacker, this answer assumes that the vertex size of 99 is a known constant.  If the 99 is meant to be a variable and is part of the input, then the problem become the standard NP-complete [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Comment: OK, but I think it would be best to explain that what this turns on is whether "99" is considered to be part of the input or not.

Comment: Is it mean both statement is wrong :Is it right that "it is NP-complete to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"

AND

 " it takes linear time to determine if a graph contains a vertex cover of size 99"???